# How can I specify my node path for a specific plugin

Tags: java, node.js, gradle

My ask is can I overide node excutable during the plugin closure? or how can i accomplish this

I am currenly working on converting .proto files into typescript models.This is a gradle project and I have been able to configure my node environment, installed ts-proto package from npm however when udring the generateProtoTask, i am currenly seeing node: no such file or directory.